# Is there a function to convert to binary from textbox?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to convert the text, e.g. "Hello World", to binary and show it in textbox2.

```cs
{
    textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

When I write a text in textbox1, I can get it by use textbox1.text. Now I want to convert it to binary (001010...) and  show it in textbox2.text in binary (001010...). How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: "Now I want to convert it to binary" - convert what to binary? What is the text here? If it's already "001010" then that's already *in* binary. It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve. (I would suggest ignoring the text boxes to be honest - demonstrate what you're trying to do in a simple console app. All you're interested in are strings and numbers, I suspect.)

Comment: Do you mean that a string of digits is typed into textBox1, which you could convert to a number with [int.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) and then convert that number to a string of binary digits with [`Convert.ToString(yourNumber, 2)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_)?

Comment: thank you for your help, I add a photo to describe what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read the updated question, I can propose the following simple binarization:

```
string stringToConvert = "Hello world!";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < stringToConvert.Length; ++i) {
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt16(stringToConvert[i]), 2).PadLeft(16, '0'));
    sb.Append('.'); // can be removed
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a *number* entered (decimal - you can change it by modifying `baseFrom`, into a binary number (you can change it by modifying `baseTo`), you can use this snippet:

```
string numberToConvert = "15";
int baseFrom = 10;
int baseTo = 2;
string result = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(numberToConvert, baseFrom), baseTo);       
Console.WriteLine(result);
```